# ProtoRPC Message Class definition

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-endpoints, protorpc

Im building a Cloud Endpoint for processing requests from a Firebase App. I want endpoint to recieve a Firebase database object like this:

```
{
"$uid": "1234",
"$idCot": "abc", 
"text": "TextHere"
}
```

So I create a Message class to handle this request:

```
MyRequest(messages.Message):
     uid = messages.StringField(1, required = True)
     idCot = messages.StringField(2, required = True) 
     text = messages.StringField(3, required = True)
```

but I cant find a way to create a valid Message Class in ProtoRPC to define that object because the "$" in the field name that Firebase adds.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this just isn't possible with ProtoRPC today. The Endpoints Java framework does support this though.

Answer (score -1):

The previous answer refers to the Endpoints Framework for Java, which is part of the Endpoints v2 release. Documentation is here: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/

Comment: There's no "previous answer" - if you need to comment on a particular answer, do so, as a *comment* for that answer.